# How to recover a SharePoint list using the version history in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, versioning, recycle-bin

How to recover a SharePoint list using the version history in SharePoint Online?

I have a list which I have deleted a few records. How can I recover them using version history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the deleted list items from recycle bin (first-level or second-stage recycle bin).

Check below documentations for detailed information:

1. [Restore deleted items from the site collection recycle bin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-deleted-items-from-the-site-collection-recycle-bin-5fa924ee-16d7-487b-9a0a-021b9062d14b)
2. [How to recover missing, deleted or corrupted items in SharePoint and OneDrive for work or school](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-recover-missing-deleted-or-corrupted-items-in-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-work-or-school-3d748edf-c072-46c9-81a4-4989056ebc87)

Comment: Is it possible with version-history too?

Comment: Deleted items cannot be restored using version history.